# How to simulate a table in jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports

since I guess there is no way to rotate a table by 90° I started to simulate one by wrapping static text and text fields together in band. I enclose each static text to its text field which suppose to have the value for that static text and then enclose all rows (combination of static and text fields) in one band. But I can not adjust the stretch type in a way that all these components play together.  Each text field has a different value and should be expandable to its content. For example field text for static text 3. All fields are set to stretch by over flow, position float, stretch type relative to band height. What are the correct adjustments for properties?

the structure is like this:

[image]

And this is how it looks like with text fields fading in each other:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put every row which can expand into a `Frame`. The frame `Position Type` should be `Float`.

Now this will keep the titles and content together.

Since you've set all other parameters accordingly, this should be enough to get the corrent layout.

Comment: So do i need to put all frames in a supper frame?

Comment: I don't see any advantage in doing that. It should be enough (with the right settings) to put every row (title and field) into a `Frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I set sub frames and text fields like this:

**Position type float, stretch type: no stretch,   stretch with overflow to true for text fields.**

**stretch with overflow to true for text fields.**

**main frame wich contains all other frames : float, relative to tallest object**