# Creating horizontal table in jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I create a structure like you see in the picture using table element in Jaspersoft studio? At the time I am using a combination of static text and text fields, but manipulating and changing this structure is not very easy and is time consuming.

[image: horizontal table]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a table in jaspersoft studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37789935/876298)

Comment: The other question was about simulating the table because I though there is no way to use the table element in a horizontal way. This one is asking if there is a way to use the table element and rotate it somehow. Should I edit the other question and ask this question as a part of the that one?

Comment: What is your new question? `How can I create a structure like you see in the picture using table element in Jaspersoft studio?` - It is not a question

Comment: How can I use the table element from basic elements horizontally? I mean column headers should be the first cell for each row and their value should be in the second cell.

Comment: Are you talking about rotation of table?

Comment: yes, exactly. Before I thought there is no way to rotate the table and I simulate a rotated table with text fields. But I wanted to be sure if it is not possible

Comment: You can pass a datasource that follows that structure..